# Phantom Omni angular velocities are 0

Tags: c++, hapi, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to build my application using the Phantom Omni haptic device and in order to [get the angular velocity of the device](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.3dsystems.com/binaries/Sensable/OH/3.5/OpenHaptics_Toolkit_API_Reference_Guide.pdf), I'm using a function from its library (**OpenHaptics**):

```
hdGetDoublev(HD_CURRENT_ANGULAR_VELOCITY, ang_vel);
```

but it returns `[0,0,0]`. I'm using the same function to get the linear velocity:

```
hdGetDoublev(HD_CURRENT_VELOCITY, lin_vel);
```

and it's working fine. (Both `lin_vel` and `ang_vel` are defined as `hduVector3Dd`)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked directly to **Open Haptics** support and this was the answer: "**This is not a bug**, `HD_CURRENT_ANGULAR_VELOCITY` doesn't apply to Touch/Omni model, because its gimbal encoder wouldn't be sufficient for accurate angular velocity calculation".

I hope it can save you some time.